# Batch Script that will scan a text file and store a particular data

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch script that will scan a text file and get the details of that txt file. For example:
There is a text file that have some content like below:

```
**428**:00, hi My name is Prakhar.
**9**:23, this is a text file.
```

so what i need is, that script will scan this file and store  **428** first and check if it is not eqauls to **000** then echo some message. after that it will check next line value i.e.**9** with **0**, if it is not zero then send some message too.

Thanks in advance
Prakhar

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I've understood your question right. Do you want to compare the integer part before ":" to 0 or do you want to compare each position of it to 0? What's the difference between x = 0 and x = 000? Or do you want compare strings instead of integers?

If you want to compare the whole int to 0, this code should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (inputfile.txt) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%b IN ("%%a") DO SET /A number=%%b
    IF !number! EQU 0 (
        ECHO 0 found!
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO 0 not found!
    )
)
PAUSE
```